# truffle version installation issue

Tags: truffle

I am running into permission issues when I try to install truffle

```
avi@avi-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle
/usr/bin/truffle -> /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
```

> keccak@1.4.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
>   npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."
>
> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/avi/.node-gyp/11.6.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/avi/.npm/_logs/2019-01-05T10_04_02_789Z-debug.log
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.
+ truffle@5.0.1
added 90 packages from 305 contributors in 7.547s
```

Comment: Try installing it without sudo .  From the error root doesnt have access to /home/avi/. I would also check what the permission are on that folder `ls -lHf`

Comment: and why not just `npm install -g truffle` ?

Comment: if this keeps playing up, take out the g flag and install it locally in folder while you result your persmission issues `npm install truffle`

Comment: ok thanks @Data_Kid, I will try those commands. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

The issue is more node / npm related than it is blockchain.

Its to do with a difference between your version of node and the gyp version

run:

```
sudo npm install -g truffle --unsafe-perm
```

It should work now